# Why would Peter's celestial abilities be tied to the existence of Ego's planet?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2, celestials

Ego tells Peter something along the lines of *If my planet and I are destroyed, then you will not be celestial anymore.* It seems to me that if Peter is a celestial like his father, or at least a *demi-celestial*, then he should continue being so even after his Father dies.

Why would Peter's power be dependent on Ego surviving?

Comment: Maybe, Celestial genes in Peter's body are still part of his father's matter hive which are connected wirelessly with the Celestial brain in control.. Once the brain died, celestial matter was as good as dead..

Comment: @Discovery I had thought something along those lines might be it, but I feel like that would have just made Peter into an Ego drone or something. Or Peter would have died when Ego died, neither of which happened. Either way, if Peter really isn't a celestial anymore, that might be the best explanation.

Comment: Ego tells Peter he will be immortal as long as he periodically "returns to the light." With the light gone, that means Peter will not be immortal anymore.

Comment: [As I understand it, please correct me if this is wrong] He still is celestial from a genetic/heritage standpoint (presumably). However, his power is to manipulate the matter that forms Ego's planet. Destroy the planet, there's nothing to manipulate. Possible analogy: if I can unlock a door with a print scanner using my own thumbprint, and the scanner is destroyed, my thumbprint does not suddenly vanish.

Comment: Because Ego is a lying sack of sh*t

Comment: @DaniellYancey I suspect Peter's innate ability is to channel energy, which is why he was able to handle the Power stone, and Ego's particular type of energy was just one thing Peter could learn to channel.

Comment: @Izkata That makes sense! My thought was similar, that he was able to handle the Power Stone since his genetics were built to handle large amounts of energy. Pairing this with your theory, I suspect that, while his ability to directly manipulate energy may be lost, he would still be able to handle the Power Stone just as well as when facing Ronan. His genetics didn't change, after all (to our knowledge).

Answer (score 4):

## Because Peter is the son of Ego the man, not Ego the planet

"The Light", the source of Ego's power, lies within the planet.

> If I don't return regularly to my planet, **and the Light within it,** this form will wither and perish.

> There's so much that I need to teach you about this planet, **and the Light within.** They are a part of you, Peter.

> Peter, death will remain a stranger to both of us **as long as the Light
>   burns within the planet.**

And as Drax observed, Ego (the planet) cannot reproduce.

> If he is a planet, how could he make a baby with your mother? He would smush her!

So Ego (the man) fathered children in an attempt to produce a child with a connection to the light within the planet.

> Out of all my labors, the most beguiling was attempting to graft my DNA with that of another species.

> Out of all my spawn, only you carried the connection to the light.

> He needs my genetic connection to the light to help destroy the universe.

And when Peter shows abilities during the catch scene, Ego is *thrilled*.

> Now, close your eyes and concentrate. Take your brain to the center of this planet. Yes!

Peter is still a celestial, or demi-celestial, or whatever he is. His genes haven't changed, and he should still have all the powers he had before he went to Ego's planet, it's just the light isn't there anymore.

Comment: But the whole point of Ego having children is to have someone else pay the price for Ego's plan. If they are both paying out of the same "bank account", as it were, then Ego's having kids doesn't help him.

Comment: @ForrestVenable No, Ego says "A single Celestial doesn't have enough power for such an enterprise. But two Celestials, well, now, that just might do." And even if you were right, that doesn't affect the question or the answer. Are you the downvoter?

Comment: Nope, just complaining.

Comment: @JDoe I quite like this interpretation/theory, very nice!

Comment: But Ego *is* the light source, right?